# How to send mail at a certain time from asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am new to asp.net. I have a project working. I need to send different mails every day at 12 am to different users. 
I need to know how to implement the method that will wake up every day at a certain period. 
Please help me with as much details possible as I am a complete beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source enterprise job scheduling system written in .NET platform that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.

You can use Windows Task Scheduler as well, but you need some specific windows permissions to do that on production server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Windows Service** that will be executed automatically at the time you want. The windows service should contain the code to send email.You can check out these links on [Simple Windows Service Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample) and [Simple Windows Service which sends auto Email alerts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16335/Simple-Windows-Service-which-sends-auto-Email-aler). You can also implement a timer in your application that can manage it. If you want to do it this way then check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49996/Schedule-Email-Through-ASP-NET-or-Schedule-Tasks-U).